# Tinder like application MongoDB database schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an app like Tinder to experiment with MongoDB.
I am wondering about the database schema.

The main idea is that a user can "like" many users but no matter how much the number of "liked" profiles grows, it is very unlikely to hit the 16MB document size ceiling, so in my design, "liked" profiles are embedded inside one's profile.

below is a sample of my users schema using mongoose

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
fullName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
phone: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
},
gender: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['male', 'female'],
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
favorites: []
});
```

On the other hand, a user might be "disliked" by my many users.
So a user should not see on his next profile search the profiles of users who "disliked" him, so in my design I created a collection that holds the ID of the user who "disliked" and the ID of the user being "disliked".

below is a sample of my blocked schema using mongoose

```
var BlockedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
BlockerUserId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
BlockedUserId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
});
```

Do you think this is a good approach? and which indexes needs to be created?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage dislike in the user collection only, you don't need a new collection.

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
fullName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
phone: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
},
gender: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['male', 'female'],
},
age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
favorites: [],
dislike[]

});
```

and search like

```
var current_user_id = userdata._id;

db.users.find({dislike:{$ne:current_user_id}})
```

The above code is not syntactically correct but it will give you an idea.

Comment: thanks @Puneet , that's another way of looking at it. How about indexing? will performance be affected by the default index on _id since on each write the index will have to be re-written?

Comment: You cannot drop the default index on the _id field. and mostly it is good to have at least a primary index. 
If there are many index which are not used than it can be a performance issue.

Comment: I am not talking about dropping the default _id index, I am asking whether I should index the favorites and dislike array

Comment: @Fouad you should index favorite array as you want to list them, but if you don't list dislike array anywhere you don't need to index it.
And the query i written in answer does not use index, as I used $ne

Comment: Out of curiosity - how would one implement the checking whether they should match or not without too many operations?